# Checkbox issues with images

Tags: ios

When select the check box second time then its show me again checked image .please help.

```
- (IBAction)CheckBox:(id)sender {
    if ((CheckBox.selected==NO)
    {
        [CheckBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        CheckBox.selected = YES;
    }
    else
    {
       [CheckBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
       CheckBox.selected =NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need edit code to:

```
- (IBAction)CheckBox:(id)sender 
{
   [CheckBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [CheckBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    if ((CheckBox.selected==NO)
    {
         CheckBox.selected = YES;
    }
    else
    {
         CheckBox.selected =NO;
    } 
}
```

Better you should set:

```
[CheckBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[CheckBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

in function configUI or your `viewDidLoad`, or in your xib...

Answer (score 0):

you have to set both state normal and selected

```
- (IBAction)CheckBox:(id)sender {
    if ((CheckBox.selected==NO)
    {
        [CheckBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [CheckBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }
    else
    {
       [CheckBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
       [CheckBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Comment: can you set breakpoint on this method then run again. Let's see if it run on both case.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)CheckBox:(id)sender {
    if ((sender.selected)
    {
        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }
    else
    {
       [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
       [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```